# Tricore Disassembling "Constants"

Tags: assembly, addressing-mode, infineon

Can someone here explain me, how the TC17** assembler works out the "movh.a and lea" addressing (hex), and how i can calculate them for myself if i have an configuration value like shown in my picture, which is defined as a "constant" or a "global".

What i want to do is, creating/assemble this 32-bit instruction for myself, but i do not make any proccess the last days. Sure, i know how to assemble with Eclipse Toolchain, but i cant use this toolchain in my programm. I am programming with PHP but this doesnt really matter, if i know how to work out this.

**As example, here is a picture with the IDApro View of the commands i have to assembly:**

[image: screenshot of IDA-Pro]

As 32-Bit Hex instruction it looks like this:

```
ASM: movh.a    a15, #@HIS(configuration_value_1)
HEX: 91 70 01 F8

ASM: lea   a15, [a15]@LOS(configuration_value_1)
HEX: D9 FF E4 67
```

What i want to do now is to work out that HEX-assembler instructions, with the right addressing to my variable. In this case its located at: "0x80177DA4".

In the instruction set, its explained like this:

[Screenshot: movh.a command](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/b2841e-1506990365.png)
[Screenshot: lea + long offset addressing mode](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/83a296-1506990477.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's causing you problem? Everything is shown in your pictures, it's just a simple matter of extracting bits.

It's easier if you reassemble the words from the little endian form. Thus:

`movh.a = F8017091`. You can see the constant is actually `8017` (no surprise there).
`lea = 67E4FFD9` This is a little bit trickier due to the silly encoding, so let's convert the top 16 bits to binary: `0110 0111 1110 0100`. Now rearrange them to get `011111 0110 100100`, then back to hex: `7DA4`

So the full address is `80177DA4`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. 
After i posted this, i viewed again at the hex-values and i found out how to figure out the movh.a problem. 
Maybe i thought a little bit too complicated because i worked 2 days at the load byte command:
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/ee9540-1506994269.png

But, this doesnt matter - as sayd i already figured out the ld.bu and the movh.a thing. But as you sayd the lea command is a bit more tricky for me. 

I dont know, how i have to rearrange the bits to get the values i need, i am very dumb in bitwise operations - i work at the "try and fail" principe..

Comment: Btw, checked the hex/address again. 
So the hex i gaved above, definitly points to 0x80177DA4, i compiled it again and load the .elf again to IDA and it's pointing to 0x80177DA4, with the HEX-instruction D9 FF E4 67

Br

Comment: Yeah I made the mistake, `E` is of course `1110` not `1100`.